# Keeping a connection with remote computers

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a series of RPi's running Raspian which need to deployed in various location around the world.

They will have internet access, but will all be behind a router. Is there an off-the-shelf solution to keep the possibility to create a SSH connection to them? I am thinking about solving problems, upgrading etc.

I am thinking of a 'server' solution where a 'client' on the RPi keep an active connection so a SSH connection can be established when required. Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented with several services including **LogMeIn Hamachi** and **Weaved** among others. I would *highly recommend* using **Weaved** because it allows you to meet your goal (SSH to pi behind a router), and the setup is painless. You may even find some other uses that are quite handy.

See the installation details at https://developer.weaved.com/portal/members/betapi.php

**Steps to be up and running:**

1. Go to http://www.weaved.com and sign up.
2. Install weaved on your pi, and follow the prompts for `SSH` (Instructions at https://developer.weaved.com/portal/members/betapi.php).
3. Go to "My Devices" at weaved.com and get the new internet accessible proxy address for your pi.
4. Enjoy!